# How do I use the .match javascript method to search an array versus a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, methods

This is a simple way of using the .match method to search through a string and then return whether or not a match was found.

```
    var match = "hello joe, how are you?".match('joe');

    if (match) {
      console.log(match[0]);
    } else {
      console.log('no match found : (');
    }
```

When trying to use the .match method to search through an array for particular string – I cannot get a return. Any advice?

```
var array = ['charlie','jeff','joe'].match('jeff');

if (array) {
  console.log(array[0]);
} else {
  console.log('no dice');
}
```

Comment: If a function output is a string; Could it then be stored as a variable and tested with .match?  For example, I need to create a function that looks at the function call.                                                                                           There is only one argument in the function. So I would like the function call to be able to be checked for various words and if so then have these various words output different statements. This is outside the scope of the question. As a newcomer; Should I create a separate question for this question?

Comment: Yes, create a new question if you have any further problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is a JavaScript string method, not array. In your example, you want to use the array [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method. It returns the index (location) of a specific item in the array, which you can then use to get that item. I recommend reading the documentation (MDN linked above) for more usage information.

```js
var array = ['charlie','jeff','joe'];

if (array.indexOf('jeff') > -1) {
  console.log(array[array.indexOf('jeff')]);
} else {
  console.log('no dice');
}
```

Comment: If a function output is a string; Could it then be stored as a variable and tested with .match?